# Servlet getRequestDispatcher.forward() work's unclear

Tags: java, servlets

I have 2 servlets, there they mapping inside `web.xml`:

```
    <url-pattern>/archiving/archive</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/archiving/reportgenerator</url-pattern>
```

From servlet `archive` I call second servlet:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/reportgenerator").forward(request, response);
```

But there error:

```
NOT_FOUND
RequestURI=/reportgenerator
```

It seems like in URL we lost "*/archiving*" before "*/reportgenerator*".

But if I add  "*/archiving*" in `reaquestDispatcher`:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/archiving/reportgenerator").forward(request, response);
```

Then I get this error:

```
NOT_FOUND
RequestURI=/archiving/archiving/reportgenerator
```

Why servlet duplicate "*/archiving*" path in 2nd case, but don't paste it in first?

Comment: Can you get to /archiving/reportgenerator directly (by pasting it into a browser URL bar) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/archiving/reportgenerator").forward(request, response);
```

to

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("../archiving/reportgenerator").forward(request, response);
```

and see if this helps.